# aspx page with gridview runs very fast in IE but 20% of the speed on Firefox

Tags: firefox, gridview, internet-explorer, asp.net

I have a simple aspx page with some search options which queries an SQLEXpress database, and it is displayed in a gridview.

For some reason, it runs lightning fast in IE but very slow in Firefox.

It has very little code, a gridview a couple of images and a couple of textboxes and a search button. It was done with Expression Web so no additional code added.

In production (not local) the speed is **very** noticiable when doing a search...

IE displays the results almost instantly...Firefox might take 3-5 seconds.

And everything else runs super fast as well in IE (update, delete etc).

Is there a reason for this ? Thanks

Comment: Since asp is not known for producing the best standard code, without a link, anything we say is just a wild guess. How well does it work in other modern browsers besides Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of extensions do you have in firefox?  something like fasterfox may be sending multiple page requests

Comment: I got Cooliris, imacros, java quick starter, mcafee siteadvisor, adobe DLM, microsoft .Net framework assistant

Coolires, imacros and mcafee siteadvisor are also in IE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with your `Firefox` Instance, maybe some creepy `Add-Ons` you installed or maybe you should disable `Firebug` which causes problems like this.

Comment: ok, I mentioned what add ons I have on the comment above...I don't have Firebug installed on the machine I am testing it.

Comment: You can run Firefox in safemode to test without addons just to be sure.